# Cloud Service authenticating multiple accounts to Nest API

Tags: node.js, nest-api

I have a cloud service that is built on NodeJs.

I want to tie in the Nest-API but I dont understand how I can manage multiple access_tokens with Firebase to receive realtime events for multiple people using my service.

Example, User A authenticates, and I get access_token 123.  Now User B authenticates and I get access_token 345.  Obviously I will store the access_tokens on my server.  But how do I get my NodeJS backend to listen to both users Nests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really only authenticate one firebase connection at a time as the authentication is pretty much global. You may want to check out Rest Streaming instead. Here is an example of it built in node https://github.com/nestlabs/rest-streaming

Comment: Yup that was my understanding as well (referring to firebase restriction).  Streaming REST will do the trick

Comment: Today Nest announced REST Multiplex, which will also do what you want if you switch protocols. See https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/multiplex-overview